# What is the default value of j when sliced with negative stride in python?

Tags: python, slice

I am trying to understand slicing. According to Python official docs:

> If i is omitted or None, use 0. If j is omitted or None, use len(s)

When k is positive, the above statement holds true. For example:

```
>>> s = 'Kaju Katli'
>>> s[:] == s[0:len(s)] #value of k is 1
True
```

When k is negative, and I put `i` as `len(s)` and `j` as 0, the element at the 0th index is not included. I know that the last element is always excluded that's why I am getting these results. For example:

```
>>> s = 'Kaju Katli'
>>> s[::-1] == s[len(s):0:-1]
False
```

So, my question is what should be the value of `j` in `s[len(s):j:-1]` to get `'iltaK ujaK'` as the result, if `s = 'Kaju katli'`? Is `None` the only possible value of `j` in such cases?

Comment: Where did you find this quote? The docs on slicing sequences say "If i or j are omitted or None, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of k)." among other things.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It's from note 4, which is solely about `[i:j]`, not about `[i:j:k]`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You can find it here https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations under Notes section

Comment: @KellyBundy Since nothing is mentioned about k, I thought it would be valid for both positive and negative values of k

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = "Kaju Katli"
j = -(len(s)+1) # or -len(s)-1 or ~len(s)
print(s[len(s):j:-1])
```

OUTPUT

```py
iltaK ujaK
```

Comment: a.k.a. `~len(s)`

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks, But this way is more understandable(I think).

Comment: Hmm, I think when you're used to using `~` for backwards indexing, it's equally understandable.

Comment: @KellyBundy I use the `~` operator for the first time. But now I think this will help then I think.

Comment: It's really quite nice for backwards indexing. First few characters are at indices 0, 1, 2. Last few characters are at indices ~0, ~1, ~2. And for example to compute the median of a list of numbers, you can use `m = len(nums); median = (nums[m] + nums[~m]) / 2`.

Comment: @SharimIqbal I was doing the same thing but then mixing point 3 from Notes section from https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations. i.e. ~len(s) would become len(s) + (~len(s)), which would result -1 and slicing would not happen at all. I think in docs, they need to specify the values of i and j w.r.t k